# Faster group by in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this

```
|customer_reference|date_and_time|
       111          2013-01-01
       111          2013-01-02
       111          2013-01-03
       222          2013-01-01
       222          2013-01-02
       333          2013-01-01
```

I want to get row with last date_and_time according to customer_reference. I've written a few queries but it is very slow. My query like that.

```
SELECT MAX(date_and_time) AS time
FROM t_table GROUP BY customer_reference
```

I have more that 600.000 row in that table.

Comment: The problem is indexes, or lack thereof. Please provide a SHOW CREATE TABLE statement for the relevant table.

Comment: Why don't you have customer_reference in the `select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add index on column `customer_reference` and execute the query below

```
SELECT customer_reference, MAX(date_and_time) AS time
FROM t_table 
GROUP BY customer_reference
```

Comment: while I agree with your answer it would also be helpfull to point siriat to some material on how to read a explain statement and how to apply the results to optimize any select query that is missing a index. Give a man a fish... etc

Answer (score 1):

its better if you add an index to your table

```
    ALTER TABLE `t_table` ADD INDEX `customer_reference` (`customer_reference`)
```

and then run your query

Answer (score 1):

**Indexes** are a feature that you can enable on your MySQL tables to increase performance.

You have to create an index on column `customer_reference`  **[Maximizing Query Performance through Column Indexing in MySQL](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3840606/Maximizing-Query-Performance-through-Column-Indexing-in-MySQL.htm)**

If we have not defined the index at creation time, we could always add one later, using the following syntax:

```
CREATE INDEX id_index ON t_table(customer_reference);
```

Comment: whether the query requires a lot of time? I try it but it is very long time to execute.